# Vuejs - pass data from parent to child with props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have started playing with `Vue` but faced an issue when trying to pass data to a component using `props`. In the code below `this.myData` (in the `Hello.vue`) is `undefined` for some reason

App.vue

```
<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      myData: 'this is my data'
    }
  },
  components: {
    Hello
  } ...
 </script>
```

Hello.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  props: ['myData'],
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
  mounted: function() {
       console.log(this.myData)
   }
} ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the child component in the parent like, so:

```
// inside app.vue
<template>
  <hello :myData='myData'></hello> // I believe this is your objective
</template> //:myData is binding the property from the components data field, without using it, you will get myData as `string` in the child component.

<script>
  export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      myData: 'this is my data'
    }
  },
  components: {
    Hello
  }
</script>
```

OP requested a way to pass in props to a child without rendering the child in the template.

So I am posting a link to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

```
Vue.component('hello', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
      <tag-names>
    )
  },
  props: {
    myData: parentComponent.myData // you need to give the parent components' data here.
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes this way is working. So the data always should go through the template? What if i just want to pass data without actually rendering it (for example some config settings)?

Comment: there are ways to accomplish data exchange between components which would not require a template rendering like using an `eventBus` or using vuex store, for your case, props seem to be the best way to go and for that you need to render the child component in the template. There is a way though, Ill update my answer for that, but that calls the render function. Does that seem okay?

Comment: Thanks! I dont mind using props. Seems the right way to do it. Just havent figure it out that the data is transmitted though the templates.

Comment: @StefanStoichev It's designed to be like this so by only looking at the parent's template we can get an idea of the dom structure, as well as data flows between it and its children, without being bothered by detailed logic(since they're in the `script` part)

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal How would `parentComponent.myData` get set in the child when the parent and child are both Vue single file components?