# VueJS pass prop to child without referencing child in parent template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 components `Parent` and `Child` - a parent can have many children. I need the children to know their position (`index`) in relation to their siblings.

**Javascript**

```
Vue.component('Parent', {
    template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
    mounted: function() {
        this.$children.forEach(function(child, index) {
            /* attempt one */
            child.$el.setAttribute('test-prop', index);

            /* attempt two */
            child.$props.testProp = index;
        })
    }
})

Vue.component('Child', {
    template: '<div><span>{{testProp}}</span><slot></slot></div>',
    props: ['testProp']
});
```

**Markup**

```
<Parent>
    <Child>some complex html</Child>
    <Child>some complex html</Child>
    <Child>some complex html</Child>
    <Child>some complex html</Child>
</Parent>
```

**attempt one** results in undefined but dom inspector shows the property has been applied

**attempt two** throws a direct prop mutation warning but the child still doesn't appear to have access to the index.

The indices are only known at the point of `Parent` being mounted, so I can't apply the prop directly to the `Child` elements in the Markup.

I cannot include `<Child v-for="child in children"> in the`Parent`template because`Parent`requires``to be used to retrieve the`Child`'s from the source HTML markup.

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs - pass data from parent to child with props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668899/vuejs-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-props)

Comment: Can't you use something like `this.$parent`?

Comment: Why are you not using `v-for` to render multiple child components?

Comment: @BasPauw I could use this.$parent, but don't want to go against best practice.

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna because I need the original markup inside the child

Comment: @Kiee what do you mean by original markup?...is it different markup for each child component?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna If i change the parent template to be include `Child v-for` rather than `slot`, i lose all the children that are included in the source markup.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is in the `created` function of the `Parent` component. Loop through the default slots and pass in an index to the `Child` VNode's `componentOptions`.

The code below assumes only child components and whitespace are present in the template, you can add additional checks against each `slot` in the foreach to ensure it is the correct component.

```
created: function() {
        var index = 0;
        this.$slots.default.forEach(function(slot) {
            if (slot.componentOptions !== undefined && slot.componentOptions.propsData !== undefined) {
                slot.componentOptions.propsData.testProp = index;
                index++;
            }
        })
    },
```

Edit:
This however doesn't have reactivity - you can't data bind using this.